# Python dns.resolver.resolve user input function

Tags: python

I am new to programming and Python. I am trying to achieve the to user input function to read the variable. Basically the following code works but uses whatever domain i specify in domain = variable

```
import dns.resolver

#i would like user inputs the domain and that domain's DNS is checked 
input('Please type your domain\n')

#unfonetly it reads from here
domain = 'example.com'
for qtype in 'A', 'AAAA', 'MX', 'NS', 'TXT', 'SOA':
    result = dns.resolver.resolve(domain,qtype, raise_on_no_answer=False)
    if result.rrset is not None:
        print(result.rrset)
        print('Record checked successfully\n')
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `input` function *returns* the value that's been entered, so put it where you want the value: `domain = input('…’)`.

Comment: Welcome to programming, Python, and Stack Overflow! I'm sorry to say that though you've asked your question well, it's not likely to be found by those that need its answer, so it's not a great fit for this part of the site, and that's probably why people are downvoting it; it's nothing personal. Please don't let it discourage you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `domain = input('Please type your domain\n')` and remove the domain assignment.

see more about the input function [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_input.asp), it basically prints the argument it receives to the console and returns the user input.

Comment: Thanks really appreciated. How could i use elif  tp bring statement rather than throwing an error i.e ```elif result.rrset is None:
        print('record doesnot exist')```

Comment: just add
`else: print('record doesnot exist')`

Comment: it's throwing this error ```raise NXDOMAIN(qnames=self.qnames_to_try,
dns.resolver.NXDOMAIN: The DNS query name does not exist: kam.yab.```

Comment: You'll need a `try`/`except` statement to handle that.

Comment: when the domain entered doesn't exist, it throws NXDOMAIN error.

just wrap the call with `try: ... except NXDOMAIN: pass`

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate your assistance.